# Python/Selenium Stale Element Reference

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I know this has been a common question but I'm relatively inexperience and I've been struggling to fix this issue.

My code is:

```
company_list = open('Company_List.txt')
  for line in company_list:
  company_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SearchTopBar"]')
  company_id.send_keys(line)
  company_id.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CompanyHeaderInfo_TearSheetReport_ReportImage"]/div/img').click()
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

And it's generating "StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which line throws exception?

Comment: Please add the exception.

Comment: Sorry, "
  File "C:\Users\kdixon\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)"

Comment: Which element is not attached to the page? Have you debugged your script? We need the line which throws an exception

Answer (score 0):

instead of `implicitly_wait` try to use [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), i think here is the problem, because you try to `click` on the element that is not on the page

```
# import this
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

for line in company_list:
    ...
    xpath = '//*[@id="CompanyHeaderInfo_TearSheetReport_ReportImage"]/div/img'

    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))
        )
        element.click()
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: Is this what you mean?

`company_list = open('Company_List.txt')
for line in company_list:
company_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SearchTopBar"]')
company_id.send_keys(line)
company_id.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
xpath = '//*[@id="CompanyHeaderInfo_TearSheetReport_ReportImage"]/div/img'
try:
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))
)
element.click()
finally:
driver.quit()`

If so, I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

StaleElementReferenceException will occur when you are holding a reference to a webelement and then the element changes either by some javascript or a page refresh. In your case, you have a reference to company_id . You are doing send_keys twice on this element. Possibly the first send_key is triggering some javascript which changes your element. ***Try to lookup company_id again before performing send_keys for the second time*** .

```
company_list = open('Company_List.txt')
  for line in company_list:
  company_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SearchTopBar"]')
  company_id.send_keys(line)
  company_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SearchTopBar"]')     
  company_id.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CompanyHeaderInfo_TearSheetReport_ReportImage"]/div/img').click()
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Also, implicit wait should be set only once at the time of initialization and is valid for the lifetime of the driver. If you desire custom wait times for each lookup, consider using explicit waits. Also, don't mix implicit and explicit waits as the result might not be predictable according to the documentation.